# hiding system keyboard in zefyr text editor flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Image of what I am trying to acompolish

[image]

So as you see from the above image, I want to create a text editor that uses my custom keyboard,
but as soon as the user presses the zefyr editor, the system keyboard will show. Is there a way to disable the keyboard?

on a normal text field, I use the following code to disable the system keyboard

```
        TextField(
              controller: _controller,
              readOnly: true,
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ZefyrEditor(        
    mode: ZefyrMode.view,
),
```

So there are no specific documentation for this,

but you can visit their change log

https://zefyr-editor.gitbook.io/docs/v/v0.7.0/release-notes/changelog

where they have described the above mentioned.

If you are using android studio you can always hover over the widget or press Ctrl + left click to see the implementation and find the inbuilt methods supported by the widget if you are not able to find out how to implement this functionality of one widget in other.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Don't want to disrespect you but seriously ? Do I need to mention how and why ? Although its already in documentation and it is an inbuilt method / function / argument for the same. I think this should be an common sense for who is looking for answer. But still fill free to improve my answer. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: The reson you should add an explanation to your answer is because people often downvote or flag answers with only code. Someone flagged your answer because of this, so it ended up in the review queue which is how I found it. Even though answers like this shouldn't be deleted, people don't always follow the rules and [one user voted to delete your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/27962695) simply because some users don't like answers with only code. If you don't want people downvoting or deleting your answer, I would recommend you add some explanation.

Comment: In this specific case, you say that it's in the documentation, so one thing you can do to improve your answer is add a link to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion I will definitely improve my further answers